# Warning Message when running Siesta tests

Tags: extjs, siesta

I have Sencha ExtJs 5.1.0.107 with Sencha CMD v 5.1.1.48 and Siesta 2.0.9, according to my Ivy dependencies:

```
    <dependency org="sencha" name="cmd" rev="5.1.1.48"/>
    <dependency org="sencha" name="ext" rev="5.1.0.107"/>
    <dependency org="bryntum" name="siesta" rev="2.0.9"/>
```

When running my tests from the command line, I am returned with the following (there are only two sample tests at the moment):

```
siesta.test:
     [echo] Siesta Path=test.html
     [echo] http://localhost/myhost/test.html
     [exec] Launching PhantomJS 1.9.7 at http://localhost/myhost/test.html
     [exec] [E] [Ext.Loader] Some requested files failed to load.
     [exec] [PASS]  test/sanity.t.js
     [exec] [E] [Ext.Loader] Some requested files failed to load.
     [exec] [PASS]  test/helloWorld.t.js
     [exec] 4 passed, 0 failed assertions took 23.73s to complete
```

Furthermore, here is my test.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.sencha.com/ext/gpl/4.2.0/resources/css/ext-all.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../siesta/resources/css/siesta-all.css">

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.sencha.com/ext/gpl/4.2.0/ext-all.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../../siesta/siesta-all.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../../siesta/siesta-coverage-all.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

My tests pass, but I am not sure why I am getting that warning message and how I can resolve it. Also, not sure if this will eventually affect any future tests. Any idea?

I have checked my JavaScript Console and it seems to be an issue with `ext-all-debug.js`:

```
[E] [Ext.Loader] Some requested files failed to load.

log @ ext-all-debug.js:5663
logx @ ext-all-debug.js:5698
Ext.apply.log.log.error @ ext-all-debug.js:5701
Ext.apply.onLoadFailure @ ext-all-debug.js:10995
(anonymous function) @ ext-all-debug.js:856
```

ext-all-debug.js is part of my preload in the harness file and points to the .js in myapp/ext/build . Any idea how this issue can be resolved?

Comment: Siesta is very naughty on Ext version it uses. We use one Ext version for Siesta and another for Application. Configure it in Harness.configure();

Answer (score 0):

More than likely your TESTS have some dependencies which are being loaded synchronously.

Open the Siesta test runner in your browser and keep an eye on your browser's JavaScript console -- it will tell you what files are being loaded synchronously with the same warning message.

Comment: thanks for your reply. See my updated question, how can I resolve the issue with ext-all-debug.js?  Any idea?

Comment: If Ext.Loader fails to load any files, you should see some 404 errors in the Network tab of your debugging tools. See what files are failing to load -- that will help narrow this down.

Comment: What you've posted is not enough for us to trouble shoot. You should try to post a simple but complete Siesta test case. It's impossible to help without seeing the full picture. Also, try to debug and make sure that the paths you use in your Harness are setup correctly.